# Plotting library

Tags: plot, wxwidgets

I'm looking for a good plotting library, with real-time plotting capabilities,  that can be used with wxWidgets.

I've looking for many such as wxMathPlot, wxArt2D or wxFreeChart(which is the one I'm actually using, but slows down when plotting many points).

So I'm acutally looking for a library that goes well with many points but I need a specific feature from wxFreeChart, which is the possiblity to draw different kinds of marks on the points.

So, nothing more and hope you can help me.

Comment: well, there are not much chart libraries for wxWidgets, but you can also check out [wxCharts](https://github.com/wxIshiko/wxCharts).

Answer (score 1):

You may find this [recent blog post](http://www.wxwidgets.org/blog/2018/08/wxchartdir-using-chartdirector-in-wxwidgets-applications/) interesting. In addition to discussing the library it is written about, it also mentions a few other ones.